# DataBase Connectivity on the client side using (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, php, database-connectivity

I have a question which really Poked me for several days... I have came across a hurdle, the problem is that i need the Php application on the server side and the database to be on the client side... and the application should communicate with each other very nicely..

Javascript was the best option coming in my mind... The problem is that i dont have any idea how do i make this thing applicable...

If any one have any knowledge for that please share that stuff with me...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You're probably looking for Ajax to accomplish that. I could be wrong. JS alone cannot talk to a DB directly, far as I know.

Comment: As far as i am not sure if this can be done, i am pretty sure that this is really not a best practice !!

Comment: Java Script is was my first option as if its not possible with javascript i will be more happy to perform this task with AJAX... :)

Do you have know relevant  tutorials for this purpose? that could help me to figure out the stuff... I will be thankful for that

Comment: database on the client side ? How will the data be shared among the users ? If you mean connect to database from client side , then you are already doing that using simple ajax .

Comment: @adi Rohan: Every client will have its own DB... in his system.

Comment: then, you already have indexedDB for that . or you can use something like taffyDB

Comment: *"Every client will have its own DB... in his system"* – You mean "table" right? If not, it's been highly suggested (here on SO) not to do that, and for so many reasons. @user2420211

Comment: @user2420211: Copy... Then any other alternative for doing this sort of stuff????

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kind of generic, so i can't determine whether you REALLY need a database stored on the client-side, and why. However if that is what you truly desire, HTML5 has client-side storage capabilities which can be used for running apps locally in the browser without having to pass data back to the server:

[Some background and usage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

[Tutorial](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9224465/HTML5_client_side_storage_tutorial_Beyond_cookies)